# How do I prevent the table from splitting by 2 in cfdocument?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

I am currently working on creating pdf file using cfdocument.

I'm able to get total pages between tags ***cfdocumentitem type="footer"*** , but ***#cfdocument.totalpagecount#*** within cfdocumentsection section is not working.

I also tried to assign this value to another variable in my cfdocumentitem many times, it didn't work either.

Briefly, what I want to do is:
My pages are split very nicely. However, there is 1 table at the end of the page, I do not want that table to be split. If it doesn't fit on the top page, I want the whole table to go to the bottom page. How can I check this? I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with CSS

```
table.endtable {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

There is an alternative solution but I think it can only be accomplished on lucee 5.3+
This will show the table header on all pages the table shows

```
table {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
```